# Can't Import Data in Condition of Date with read.csv.sql

Tags: sql, r

**Environment:** R

**Goal:** import all data from a csv where Start Date is before 10/1/2013

**Data Structure:**

```
Trip ID Duration    Start Date  Start Station

4576    63  8/29/2013 14:13 South Van Ness at Market

4607    70  8/29/2013 14:42 San Jose City Hall

4130    71  8/29/2013 10:16 Mountain View City Hall

4251    77  8/29/2013 11:29 San Jose City Hall
```

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(sqldf)
tripData <- read.csv.sql("201402_trip_data.csv", sql = "select * from file where 'Start Date' <= '10/1/2013'",header = TRUE, eol = "\n")
```

**Question:**

There's no warnings in R, but the result shows that only 11 variables name were imported, but no observation in the tripData.

Comment: You should also label your question with the specific version of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.).

Comment: Your `Start Date` timestamp values appear to be in a non-standard SQL format.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a problem:

```
select * from file where 'Start Date' <= '10/1/2013'
```

This is telling SQL to lexicographically compare the string `'Start Date'` to `'10/1/2013`'.  I believe that this will never be true, because the letter `S` compares *after* the number `1`.  You need to use backticks, not quotes, around the column name.  This is the query which you intended to run:

```
select * from file where `Start Date` <= '10/1/2013'

> tripData <- read.csv.sql("201402_trip_data.csv", sql = "select * from file where `Start Date` <= '10/1/2013'",header = TRUE, eol = "\n")
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for your help. I just tried to run the code from you, there comes out a warning: Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: Start Date.

Comment: Are you sure that this column exists?  What version of SQL are you using?  Can you shared the `CREATE TABLE` statement you used to create the `file` table?

Comment: Yes, there exists a column named as "Start Date". The CSV file was created by other people, I just intend to import some of data into R. I captured a picture of the table in my post, please have a view.

Comment: Show us what the column names are in the object `tripData`.  Maybe you have spaces or something else in your header names.